# I am trying to create a basic discord bot in replit and I have written a code for it but it keeps showing me an error when I run it

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord Bot in [replit](https://replit.com)

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
  client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "+")
  @client.event
  async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
  @client.event    
  async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member}has joined the server')
  @client.event  
  async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member}has left the server')  


client.run('token')
```

This is the code that is giving me an error.

Comment: Please regenerate your token in the [Discord Developer Console](https://discord.com/developers). Anyone can hack your bot.

Comment: What error are you getting? In replit when copying text from the console, you will need to highlight and right click code to copy  it, as `CTRL`+`C` does not copy text. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to add your error.

Comment: @UltimateCreeper You can make out from the code. The whole code is a messed up file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning. Let's see how do we do it. :D

I will do it step by step and make you understand every single statement. :)

#### Step 1: Importing Package

Import the package `discord` and import the `commands` subpackage as well.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Step 2: Define your `Bot` variable

We are now going to define the bot so as to use it using our package.

```
client = commands.Bot(prefix="+", case_insensitive=True)
```

*Note: I have added `case_insensitive` as it allows us to use the command any way we want. For example, you can enter the command `+help` in ways: `+HELP`, `+Help` and all the other possible combinations.*

#### Step 3: Creating `on_ready` event for our Bot.

We will now create an `on_ready` function for the bot so that we confirm the bot is online.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I am now online, my creator. :D")
```

#### Step 4: Create `on_member_join` event for our Bot.

We will now create the function to check for member joining the server and do the actions we want it to do.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    join_member_channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await join_member_channel.send(f"{member.mention} has joined the server!")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

*Note: The `id` in the `join_member_channel` is the ID of the channel you want the bot to send message in. So which ever channel you are using to create join log, get the ID and paste it instead of `id`.*

#### Step 5: Create `on_member_remove` event for our Bot.

We will now create a function to check for member leaving the server and do the actions we want it to do.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    leave_member_channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await leave_member_channel.send(f"{member.mention} has left the server")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

*Note: The `id` in the `leave_member_channel` is the ID of the channel you want the bot to send message in. So which ever channel you are using to create join log, get the ID and paste it instead of `id`.*

Step 6: Run the bot.
Simplest YEAH!

```
client.run("ADD YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

---

### Compiled Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(prefix="+", case_insensitive=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I am now online, my creator. :D")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    join_member_channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await join_member_channel.send(f"{member.mention} has joined the server!")
    await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    leave_member_channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await leave_member_channel.send(f"{member.mention} has left the server")
    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run("ADD YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

---

Hope I was able to explain it well to you. Please ask if any doubt, in the comments. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: I wouldn't call it compiled code, as Python is interpreted. Probably better to call it finished code.

Comment: @UltimateCreeper I don't mean conversion into machine language or something. Meaning of compiled is just simple english, combining all the pieces into one single code block.

Comment: thanks I have now resolved my issue and have successfully made a bot which replies randomly to the commands clears messages etc but I cannot make it into a arrival or departure bot like you did i followed your code and some others from the internet but it just wont work when a person joins the testing server it just does nothing apart from that it is working fine

Comment: Oh! I get it. I forgot to add one thing. To let other command work we have to add `await bot.process_commands(message)`. Let me change the code.

Comment: Okay, Now the events would let other commands run. @DOvahboi